# "Client.js" error and Sqlite error when start the bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, discord.js, bots

so when i tried to start my discord bot, this error message appeared

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Programs\!Discord Bot\Pterodactyl Manager Bot>node .
Starting the bot...
C:\Users\User\Documents\Programs\!Discord Bot\Pterodactyl Manager Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:42
    } catch {
            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:136:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:197:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:618:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:11:18)

C:\Users\User\Documents\Programs\!Discord Bot\Pterodactyl Manager Bot>
```

i use node.js version 9.11.1 because i use sqlite module, if i use node.js version 14.15.4 this error appeared

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Programs\!Discord Bot\Pterodactyl Manager Bot>node .
Starting the bot...
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Programs\!Discord Bot\Pterodactyl Manager Bot\node_modules\sqlite\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v83-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\User\Documents\Programs\!Discord Bot\Pterodactyl Manager Bot\node_modules\sqlite\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3-binding.js
- C:\Users\User\Documents\Programs\!Discord Bot\Pterodactyl Manager Bot\node_modules\sqlite\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js
- C:\Users\User\Documents\Programs\!Discord Bot\Pterodactyl Manager Bot\node_modules\sqlite\main.js
- C:\Users\User\Documents\Programs\!Discord Bot\Pterodactyl Manager Bot\commands\control\kill.js
- C:\Users\User\Documents\Programs\!Discord Bot\Pterodactyl Manager Bot\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\Programs\!Discord Bot\Pterodactyl Manager Bot\node_modules\sqlite\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3-binding.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Programs\\!Discord Bot\\Pterodactyl Manager Bot\\node_modules\\sqlite\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\sqlite3-binding.js',
    'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Programs\\!Discord Bot\\Pterodactyl Manager Bot\\node_modules\\sqlite\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\sqlite3.js',
    'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Programs\\!Discord Bot\\Pterodactyl Manager Bot\\node_modules\\sqlite\\main.js',
    'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Programs\\!Discord Bot\\Pterodactyl Manager Bot\\commands\\control\\kill.js',
    'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Programs\\!Discord Bot\\Pterodactyl Manager Bot\\index.js'
  ]
}

C:\Users\User\Documents\Programs\!Discord Bot\Pterodactyl Manager Bot>
```

, that's the error message when i use 14.15.4 node js version, can someone help me on this issues?

oh, and if you asking what's my index.js code, there we go...

```
const start = Date.now()
console.log('Starting the bot...');
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const { Token } = require("./settings.json");
const { readdirSync } = require('fs');
const { join } = require('path');
const settings = require("./settings.json");
const { Intents, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const Client = require('./struct/Client');
const tamako = new Client({
    clientSettings: {
            disableMentions: 'everyone'
        ,   ws: {
                intents: Intents.NON_PRIVILEGED
            }
        ,   presence: {
                activity: {
                        name: 'Ptero Bot'
                    , type:'WATCHING'
                    , url: 'Falixnodes.net'
                }
            }
        ,   restTimeOffset: 100,
    }
    ,   bootTimeStart: start
    ,   commandgroups: [
            'bot'
        , 'control'

    ]
    ,   prefix: 'f!'
    ,   uploadchannel: '806000175982182443'
    ,   owners: ['397338324328775680']
    ,   token: Token,
});
tamako.queue = new Map()
for (const dir of tamako.config.commanddir) {
    for (const file of readdirSync(join(__dirname, 'commands', dir)).filter(f => f.split('.').pop() === 'js'))
        tamako.commands.add(require(`./commands/${dir}/${file}`));
}

tamako.embederror = function (text) {
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Error")
        .setDescription(text)
        .setColor(settings.embed.color.error)
        .setFooter(settings.embed.footer)
        .setTimestamp();
    return embed;
};
tamako.noperm = function (text) {
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`${text} you don't have permission to use this command.`)
        .setColor(settings.embed.color.error)
        .setFooter(settings.embed.footer)
        .setTimestamp();
    return embed;
};

for ( const event of readdirSync(join(__dirname, 'events')).filter( f => f.split('.').pop() === 'js'))
  tamako.on(event.split('.')[0], require(`./events/${event}`).bind(null, tamako));

tamako.connect();
```

, sorry if it's too long, acctually it's not me who code it, it's from [this github page](https://github.com/BearTS/Pterodactyl-v1-DiscordBot), i only modify it's little bit,